# hide alertview before call return?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have alertview with button when user click the button the program enter a long time loop 
I want to hide the alertview before I call this long while 
I have searched for class delegate and I got

```
// Called when a button is clicked. The view will be automatically dismissed "**after**" this call returns
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

how can hide the alert view **before** this call return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution which i had founded after many triers

```
[self performSelector:@selector(`call Method`) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

instead of `clickedButtonAtIndex`. `didDismissWithButtonIndex` is called *after* the alert view has been dismissed.

You can not "immediately hide" an alert view, because any changes to the user interface are done only when the program control returns to the main runloop.

(A better solution would probably be to move the long running task to a background thread so that the main thread is not blocked and the user interface stays responsive.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this :

```
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
```

into

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: I have tried this bef- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{


    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Tap to retry"])
    {
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
        int counter=0;
        while (1) {
            counter++;
        }
    }


}
ore not working tried your self as the following

Comment: Let me get this right then you want to dismiss the UIAlertView before you enter the loop?